# How does the storage limit work on Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I recently created an account on Outlook.com and installed the Outlook Communicator Plugin in Outlook 2007 in order to sync my existing mail onto Outlook.com. It was going fine for a few hours (the only way I could tell that it was even syncing was by observing the network bandwidth activity). Now, the syncing appears to have stopped, and the log file for Outlook Communicator says the following:

```
Time: 8/4/2012 12:54:35 PM
Error in Mail
Error with Send/Receive.
There was an error synchronizing your folder hierarchy. Error : 8007000e.
```

I searched for error 8007000e and found out that it may have something to do with a storage problem, which leads me to believe that I am out of storage on Outlook.com. However, Outlook.com's [help page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/outlook/email-storage-limits) states the following:

> Microsoft Outlook includes email storage that expands to provide you with as much storage space as you need. Your inbox capacity will automatically increase as you need more space. If your inbox grows too fast, you might not be able to send or receive any more messages.

I guess that my problem is that I added a lot of emails too fast. Does anyone know how long it takes for the capacity to "automatically increase"?

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific amount of time. If you use your Outlook.com account for a while (basically showing Outlook.com that you're not a spammer), Outlook.com will figure out that you're not a spammer and automatically increase your quota.

Alternatively, you can verify your account by going to http://sms.live.com and verifying your mobile number (no need to sign up for notifications - simply verifying your mobile number will work).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to tell what your quota is, or at least whether it has been increased?